# wrap/replace sentences in Greek encoding using sed

Tags: bash, sed, utf-8

I have a txt file in UTF8 encoding, containing (mostly) words in Latin alphabet (including accented letters), and (a few) words in Greek (including diacritics).

I would like to find all Greek "sentences" (i.e. words in the Greek alphabet, separated by spaces and/or common punctuation, but no Latin character), and replace those with the same sentence, but wrapped within a \greektext{...} LaTeX command.

E.g. Пάτριος πολιτεία should be replaced by \greektext{Пάτριος πολιτεία}

The basic question is then, whether it is possible to select groups of Greek words, i.e. Greek "sentences", as defined above, with sed.

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex like this might do you justice:

```
/([\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF]+\s+[\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF]+)+/
```

`\u0370-\u03FF` is the Greek and Coptic block and `\u0400-\u04FF` is the Cyrillic block.

Doing `charinfo` on all of your specified characters these blocks will cover you:

```
% charinfo Пάτριος πολιτεία
U+041F CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER PE [Lu]
U+03AC GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA TONOS [Ll]
U+03C4 GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU [Ll]
U+03C1 GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO [Ll]
U+03B9 GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA [Ll]
U+03BF GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON [Ll]
U+03C2 GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA [Ll]
U+03C0 GREEK SMALL LETTER PI [Ll]
U+03BF GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON [Ll]
U+03BB GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA [Ll]
U+03B9 GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA [Ll]
U+03C4 GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU [Ll]
U+03B5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON [Ll]
U+03AF GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA TONOS [Ll]
U+03B1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA [Ll]
```

But AFAIK sed doesn't handle multibyte character very well. The following Perl script will work though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
use open qw(:std :utf8);
s/([\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]+\s+[\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]+)+/\\greektext{$&}/u'
```

And usage:

```
perl my_script.pl < my_input > my_output
```

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 71: Invalid range end

Comment: Of course I did (many thanks!), and I've tried to implement it with:

#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/([\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF]+\s+[\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF]+)+/\\\textgreek\{&\}/g" $1

resulting in an "Invalid range end" error message :-(

Comment: Replacement of single characters (but given as a two byte hex combination) works though: sed -i "s/\xce\xb9/\\\textgreek\{&\}/g" $1 What I cannot yet define are words of a given range of characters, even if given in hex representation.

Comment: Replacement of single characters in a (conveniently large) range is obtained with sed -i "s/[\xce\x91-\xcf\x8e]/\\\textgreek\{&\}/g" $1 Yet not words.

Comment: ... which can be enlarged at most to \xce\x86-\xcf\x9c (a wider range on either ends yields an Invalid collation character error)